# Entity Framework setting navigation property null in zero to one association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a Zero to one association between two tables.
For instance, I have entity `Car` and Entity `License` and a car can have 0 or 1 License.
(A car can have one license, but a license can have 0 or 1 car)
When I try to remove a car's license, by setting `Car.License = null` i get an exception such as:

A relationship from the 'Car_Licence' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'License' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

I want the license to stay in the main Licenses DbSet, and i want it's reference to Car to remain, all I want it that the Car's license be set to null.

What am i missing?

Comment: Can you show us your mapping/removal code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Car.License` to `null` conflicts with association you have set, where car must have one license set. You need to change your association so that car can have one or zero licenses for it to work.

**EDIT**

You will have to set both ends of association to zero or one if you want to null the property.

Comment: The association is Car can have zero or one license, and License needs to have one Car. that is what I don't understand.

Comment: In that case, try to setting car property on license object to null instead.

Comment: You do not understand. I cannot set License.Car to null cause it has ONE constraint! I want it that way, all i want is to set Car.License to null and it should work cause it's (Zero or One) but it gives me that error message like i'm deleting something.

Comment: The way you set up your association uses a car key column in license table. Car does not have any property other than your navigation property to hold license reference. All changes to this association must be done through License entity.

Comment: Think about it this way: If you set your car license property to null, where would this license car property now point? It has to be a car (as it has ONE contraint), but it cannot be the car from wich you deleted the license, so the contraint gets violated.

Comment: So what you're saying is have a 0..1 to 0..1 asscociation?

Comment: Yes, if you want to set Car's License property to null you have to set both ends of association to 0..1

Comment: I don't think that would work. The question asks for a situation where `license.Car.License == null` is true. That is impossible with a single association. I think this is unsolvable unless you create two separate associations, so that each license has one car, each car has a collection of licenses, and each car separately has zero or one active license.

Comment: It did "work" but not really what i need, it just doesn't give me an exception anymore. I think that two seperate associations are the trick.